# Building project failes and causes connection reset

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

The project i am working on was developed long time ago and was running successfully. now, I want to have access to it again and run it to see some results.

When I try to build the project, I receive the following errors and Connection_Reset" message.

**updated gradle:app**:

```
plugins{
    id 'com.android.application'
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "example.com.thninxnet_00"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.5.jar')
}
```

**updated gradle:project**:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**updated Error**:

```
connection reset
```

Comment: You might need to add `google()` under `allprojects.repositories` as well.

Comment: I think you have pull it from `github`. Git don't save your secured file. It means when you  push projects to github some source code deletes automatically. According to that picture which you gave the problem is in your dependencies(having issue on implementation). Do as @maurice said. I think some libraries are missing and try to sync again.

Comment: @maurice actually now I am receviing that error mentioned above.did u get it?

Comment: @LetsamrIt You are having issue in versioning. Cause, That project was in older version And, now you are using updated version of `jar` and some internet libraries. I have no idea how to fix that. So, Sorry!

Comment: you place google() above jcenter() both `buildscript` and `allprojects`

Comment: @Tungken unfortunately, it did not solve thte issue

Comment: Have you tried to increase the gradle version? -> `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'`

Comment: and also in the end of your dependencies, you mistyped `implementation` word -> `compiimplementationle 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.1'`

Answer (score 1):

You are using a `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` of `30` but your `buuldToolsVersion` is `25`, so just for compatibility replace:

```
buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
```

With:

```
buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"
```

And also replace:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

With:

```
plugins{
   id 'com.android.application'
}
```

And update us with the outcome.

EDIT:
Also`Invalidate Caches` too:

File -> Invalidate Caches -> Invalidate and Restart

EDIT 2:

Connection reset can occur when `gradle` can't connect to `servers` to retrieve required `libraries`, so what you can do is:

1. Check if your `internet` connection is stable, it maybe due to unstable internet connection.
2. If you have a stable internet connection then problem may be connection to `gradle servers` maybe blocked, so use a VPN (which changes your IP) and try rebuilding your project again.
3. Another problem maybe your `Antivirus` software or `Firewall` maybe blocking `Android Studio`, so to be sure disable both your Firewall and Antivirus software and rebuild your project.

Comment: i updated the question. i followed the steps you proposed but i received the error post in the updated question..please read it

Comment: @LetsamrIt I edited my answer, check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Can't say anything about the later error but the connection reset error during build is sometimes due to unstable internet connection. And maybe this unstable internet connection is the reason for failed syncing and the later errors.

Answer (score 0):

**`google()`** has been added in Gradle v4 , So ensure you are using correct Gradle plugin versions

Please try to update your Project level Gradle file with

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
```

and in your `gradle-wrapper.properties`  add this line

```
distributionUrl=\
  https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-x-all.zip
```

Eitherwise in the older versions of Android Studio you can use the equivalent for `google()` using the `maven` construct but try to put right after `jcenter()`

```
maven {
    url 'https://maven.google.com'
}
```